# watir - focus on window without title

Tags: watir, title

I use watir in RadRails IDE. I need to attach a new window by it's title, but in my web application there could be an error, the title is missed. So I can't use the code:
 `ie3=Watir::IE.attach(:title, 'Mt Title')`.

The page is loaded and I can perform some actions there. Is there way to focus on that window not using page title? Or how can I define page title?

Maybe there is a possibility of choosing a window by name or some other attribute and if I do not know the exact name then can I define it or define names of all opened windows?

Comment: I could not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one IE window this would work:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, //)
```

If you want to check if there is a page with a title, try something like this:

```
begin
  browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, "teh codez")
rescue Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException
  puts "could not find browser"
end
```

Comment: how can I check if some page title exist? Something like this - if ie1.title("NewPage").exist? (this not work)

Comment: how find and print all existed titles?